# Laravel 5.2 - Scheduled Cron Job in Share Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, cron, schedule

i created a scheduled for my post adds, after expire date change the visible to zero "false".

My kernel

```
$schedule->call(function () {

            foreach(Post::all() as $post)
                {
                    if(Carbon::now() > $post->expire_date){                          
                        $s = new Post;                        
                        $data = array(
                        'visible' => 0,
                        );
                        $s->where('id', '=', $post->id)->update($data);
                    }
                }
        })->everyMinute();
```

When i do in Local a command:

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

it work well! But IN MY HOSTIND IT DOEN'T WORK! i tryed to add a job to my share hosting like this:

```
php /home/dixardin/public_html/regalo/regalo/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The structure folder is like the picture: 
[image]

In my folder laravel i have the artisan file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `php-cli /home/dixardin/public_html/regalo/regalo/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem, by using php-cli.... i think it will show response in php-cli? how we can access php-cli in cpanel( shared hosting )

Answer (score 1):

There can be two errors

1. PHP Version
2. Debug

---

1. You can try to replace `php` with `php70` in `php /home/dixardin/public_html/regalo/regalo/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`. Maybe the webhost has php 7 (or another version) not renamed it to php.
2. You can look in the debug what kind of error there's generated. `php /home/dixardin/public_html/regalo/regalo/laravel/artisan schedule:run` will be the new command.

Hope this works!